# LilyPond multiline lyrics

Tags: lilypond

Having this example LilyPond snippet, I'm getting two strange things.

```
\score{
  <<
    \new Voice = "voicea" \relative { g'4 a b c g a b c }
    \new Lyrics \lyricmode {
      { a b c d }
      <<
         \new Lyrics \lyricsto "voicea" \lyricmode { e f g h }
         \new Lyrics \lyricsto "voicea" \lyricmode { i j k l }
      >>
    }
    \new Voice = "voiceb" \relative { g'4 a b c g a b c }

  >>
}
```

1. The last two lyrics lines are placed under the both music lines. I want all lyrics to go in-between them.
2. By some reason, the lyrics don't line up correctly with the notes. The first quarter note in the second bar has no lyric.

Can you help me understand what is going on, and preferably come up with a solution.

Here is the document: http://lilybin.com/o6atu2/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One Lyrics context makes one line of lyrics. If you want sequential lyrics, you need to put them into the same context. To target some notes in a voice, you can always create a named voice into another. This is what it looks like:

```
\score{
  <<
    \new Voice = "voicea" \relative { 
      g'4 a b c 
      \new Voice = "voiceb" { g a b c }
    }
    \new Lyrics
    <<
      \lyricsto  "voicea" { \lyricmode { a b c d } }
      \lyricsto  "voiceb" { \lyricmode { e f g h } }
    >>
    \new Lyrics   \lyricsto  "voiceb" { \lyricmode { i j k l } }
    \new Voice = "voicec" \relative { g'4 a b c g a b c }
  >>
}
```

The lilybin document is here: http://lilybin.com/4vsiem/1
[image: example lilypond output]

Comment: Thank you! Good suggestion of a generic way of resolving this issue. Now I'll try adapting this to my more complex arrangement.

Answer (score 2):

I don't use Lyrics and I can't tell you what's wrong exactly in your example.
But this is a simple working example:

```
\version "2.18.2"

<<
  \new Voice \relative {
    g'4 a b c g a b c
  }
  \addlyrics { a b c d e f g h } % 1st stanza
  \addlyrics { _ _ _ _ i j k l } % 2nd stanza

  \new Voice \relative {
    g'4 a b c g a b c
  }
>>
```

Comment: This would likely work, but maintaining these underscores will be quite troublesome with a more complex song. I'll upvote it, but the suggestion by @Paco is more relevant.